# Opencv in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, cmake

I want to create OpenCV projects using Eclipse. I am able to do so by setting the property of each project as mentioned at OpenCV [docs here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html)

But I want to get rid of this problem of setting property everytime whenever i create a new project. I think that I can do so by putting a `CMakeList.txt` in my project.

**Problem:** Please tell me, how can I put a `CMakeList.txt` in Eclipse to use OpenCV libraries?

**PS:** I already have a `CMakeList.txt`